# How to show error message in Try Catch statement

Tags: winrt-xaml

It seems you can not use Await to show error message in Try-Catch Statement:

```
MessageDialog mError = new MessageDialog("Error: You entered: " +  txtNbr.text , "Not a Number");
await mError.ShowAsync();
```

How to show error message in Try-Catch Block ??

Thanks

------- Update 
I got error for this " Unspecific Error "

```
public async void Populate()
        {

            try
            {

                string PrintText = "";

                //--- Create a Run of plain text and some bold text.
                Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Run myRun1 = new Run();
                myRun1.Text = "testing testing testing  \n  1213131313 \n";
                P1.Inlines.Add(myRun1);
                textContent.Blocks.Add(P1);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;

            }

            if (ErrorMessage != "")
            {
                MessageDialog mError = new MessageDialog(ErrorMessage, "Error");
                await mError.ShowAsync();
                ErrorMessage = "";
            } 

        }
```

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817216/what-is-the-proper-way-to-show-a-winrt-messagedialog-due-to-a-caught-exception

Comment: I still got error msg. Am I missing anything?

Comment: On which line ? Can you post more error detail ?

Comment: At this line :   textContent.Blocks.Add(P1); Where textContent is the RichTextBlock.

Comment: P1 is the Paragraph for RichTextBlock which is on the Page. Without Try-Catch, there is no error. With Try-Catch, there is err msg BUT still show the result. What could be the problem?

Comment: The issue you're discussing now is different than the question you originally posed.  Consider posting that issue as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx): "An await expression can't occur in a catch block or a finally block."

You could restructure your code to set a flag in the catch block and show the message dialog outside of the catch block if the flag is set.

Comment: Do I need to use async keyword for the method base on your suggestion?