# Opening a window without an icon in the taskbar

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

The "Options" in Firefox opens:

- No icon on the taskbar
- Are blocking the ability to restore to the main window.

How to do the extension to other windows, type:

```
chrome://browser/content/search/engineManager.xul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an icon and not in taskbar? You must mean a dialog window.

```
var ww = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);

ww.openWindow(window, "chrome://browser/content/search/engineManager.xul", "_blank", "chrome,dialog,modal,centerscreen,resizable", null);
```

If you want the no icon and nothing showing in taskbar, you MUST pass a first argument window, the dialog will be tied to this window, AND you MUST pass `dialog` and `modal` as a feature

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowWatcher#openWindow%28%29

can also use `Services.ww.openWindow` instead of `var ww = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher);` IF you have imported `Services.jsm`.

That guy @nmaier is asleep right now :haha: but when you wake up nmaier man, is there anywhere that lists all the options we can use in the `features` argument?

---

Edit: Update:

Reason it's not working is because from your scope `window` is not defined. So set window to the most recent window like by going: `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')`. Or you can use `null` in place of `'navigator:browser'`.

SDK way because thats what it looks like you're doing from your comment:

```
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

Services.ww.openWindow(Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'), "chrome://browser/content/search/engineManager.xul", "_blank", "chrome,dialog,modal,centerscreen,resizable", null);
```

Comment: Sure [there is a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) and it seems to be up-to-date. Passing `modal` isn't required. [Modal windows should be avoided most of the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361493/why-are-modal-dialog-boxes-evil), though. Don't take Stack Overflows opinion for it, there are plenty of guru UX-folks expressing the same opinion, incl. the Mozilla UX folks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that man. That's an awesome list. Yeah modal windows suck I agree, except alerts when debugging, it like holds up the whole process.

Comment: I tested it man, if I don't pass `modal`, its adding a window to the taskbar (im using winxp)

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't, just wanted to point out that `modal` is considered evil (most of the time).

Comment: Is there a way to do non-taskbar showing windows without being modal? Like loading a chrome url in a `deck` that i put in a `panel` or something?

Comment: It does not work. 
Traded: Components.classes > let {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");I still do not work.

Comment: I fixed it see update, reason it doesn't work is because `window` is not defined in your scope. It's not throwing error because it's fine for first argument of `openWindow` to be `null` or `undefined` or `0`.