# How to open another Popup window within a popup window?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm opening a pop up window, and I want to open another pop up window FROM that existing pop up window. But when I click the image button, nothing happens.

```
 protected void ViewImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
            ImageButton ViewTicketImageBtn = sender as ImageButton;
            GridViewRow GridViewRow = (GridViewRow)ViewTicketImageBtn.NamingContainer;
            try
            {
                //some code here
                this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">viewTicketDetails();</script>");

            }
    }
```

This is my code in Site.Master. For the viewTicketDetails()

```
    var win;
    function viewTicketDetails() {
        win = window.open('ViewTicketDetailsPage.aspx'
                                , 'TicketDetails'
                                , 'width=1040, height=600, innerHeight=600, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, scrollbars=yes, left=0'
                                , '_blank');
        win.focus();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider that nesting modal windows isn't a great idea. Generally modal windows give the user a bad experience.

Perhaps it is worth considering some alternatives.

Please check some advise on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361481/when-are-modal-dialogs-truly-necessary), [stack exchangeUX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15858/good-alternatives-for-replacing-multiple-nested-modal-dialogs) and [this blog](https://developer.appway.com/screen/ShowSingleRecipe/selectedRecipeId/1390246496349) - not mine ;)

Hope it helps.